# Vespa idles fine, stalls with throttle

Tags: engine, motorcycle, stall

I have a 2006 Vespa LX 150 that starts up and idles perfectly but, when giving it any gas at all, it starts to stall and it is not delivering enough power to move forward. I let it idle for a good 5-10 minutes and kept trying but to no avail.

It has never acted strangely like this at all (never anything weird with the drive mechanics). I drove it two days ago and it was perfect but it may be worth noting that it was in the rain. However, I've done that several times and there was never an issue.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you seen a change in temperature/altitude over the past few days?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me as though your carburettor has a blocked main jet.  I'd remove it and clean it out with compressed air or carburettor cleaner.  The idle circuit uses a different jet which is probably with it ticks over perfectly but dies (probably of fuel starvation) as soon as you open the throttle.

Comment: Is it possible that this got blocked by a leaf or something? I went to check it out today and it was working 100% perfectly. I have no idea what changed since it was just sitting there the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try replacing your Air-filter, if you haven't done during your last service check-up
2. Also check your Spark Plug for carbon soot and clean if necessary